# What are the specs for material design icon?

Tags: inkscape, svg, google-material-design

I would like to draw an app launcher icon with Inkscape but the official guide seems to miss some specs. In my understanding, to design a material design icon I just need to put some shapes together with different layers, and add drop shadow and long shadow for them respectively so they will have different elevations. However I can't find the specs for drop shadow and long shadow described in svg. Could anyone tell me the best specs that obey the guidelines?